# Firebird's clause where like array string

Tags: php, firebird

Maybe someone knows, how to write clause WHERE for array string.

I have like this

```
$array = array('MON/D', 'MON/D/G', 'POD/S', 'POD/S/G);
$string = join(',', $array);
$query = "select * from rswo where obk in (" . $string . ")";
```

But this don't working, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround each element in the array with quotes.

```
$array = array("'MON/D'", "'MON/D/G'", "'POD/S'", "'POD/S/G'");
```

Comment: Ok, working but array must be like this array("'MON/D'","'MON/D/G'")